# File too long exception

Tags: c#, file, delete-file

I am trying to delete file from remote computer like this:

```
fileinfo undelteablefile = new fileinfo(
 @"\\CompName\c$\documents and settings\UserName\local settings\temporary internet files\content.ie5\k9ef0hmj\%d7%a9%d7%a2%a8%20%d7%9c%20%d7%a2%93%d7%9b%d7%95%d7%9f%20%d7%98%d7%9d%a0%d795%d7%9c%d7%d7%95%d7%92%d7%99%20%d7%97%95%d7%93%d7%a9%d7%99 [1] .jpg");

undeleteablefile.delete();
```

It gave me an exception that the file name or path are too long.

I tried adding `\\?\` but it didnt work... Why is this happening and what to do to solve this?

Comment: What is `\\?\ ` supposed to do? Also, what you posted is not valid C#. The string delimiters are `"` not pairs of single quotes.

Comment: Am curious as to why you're wanting to delete the one specific file programmatically? Is is incriminating/NSFW? Anywhoo, there's always [crap cleaner](http://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER)

Answer (score 2):

Map a network share to one of the directories closer to the file.  Try deleting it with a wildcard.

Answer (score 2):

There are three approaches that I have used, but be warned that they require unmanaged P/Invoke code. Not much, so you can probably copy/paste if you don't understand how it works.

1. [Use the 8.3 filenames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364989.aspx) (ala DOS compatible filenames)
2. Use the \?\ syntax that you mention. However, I don't believe that you can use it directly from C# - you will need to invoke the native methods. Note - this has security implications, as the string is not parsed, but passed directly to the filesystem.
3. Use the unmanaged File APIs.

[This is a great series of blog posts that address exactly this issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton.aspx).

Erick

Answer (score 1):

The long path prefix `\\?\` can only be used with non UNC paths.
Use the `\\?\UNC\` pefix for UNC paths instead and call the Win32 API function `DeleteFile`.
See the following [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#short_vs._long_names) article for more information about naming files and paths.

Here is a small example:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool DeleteFile(string lpFileName);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string yourLongUncPath = @"\\?\UNC\server\path";

  if(DeleteFile(yourLongUncPath))
  {
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Successfully deleted file...");
  }
}
```

Please note, that you have to use the Unicode version of `DeleteFile` to use the 
long path prefix `\\?\UNC\`.

Comment: what is this UNC\server\path?
server is the computer name?
and what is the UNC?

Comment: @yosiroz: Yes, server is the computer name. \\?\UNC is the long path prefix for UNC paths.

Comment: i tried this and the "DeleteFile(yourLongUncPath)" return false wich mean it didnt work... have an idea why?

Comment: @yosiroz: Did you check the last error code? What does Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() return?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the end of the file-name it seems that Windows is not able to handle it due to obscure characters in the name.

I used the [online facility](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/) to decode the file name part, which could theoretically explain why its not able to delete it.

> %d7%a9%d7%a2%a8%20%d7%9c%20%d7%a2%93%d7%9b%d7%95%d7%9f%20%d7%98%d7%9d%a0%d795%d7%9c%d7%d7%95%d7%92%d7%99%20%d7%97%95%d7%93%d7%a9%d7%99
>   [1](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/) .jpg

When converted it looks like this, with US-ASCII

> ����� �� ��������� ������95��������� ��������� [1](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/) .jpg

Likewise for UTF-8

> שע� ל ע�כון טם��95ל�וגי ח�דשי [1](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/) .jpg

Have you not considered that you may have to url-decode it to make it more safer and thereby reducing the length of the filename itself.